# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.how to solve?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i have `mysql database on aws` when i try to access to through java progarm it give exception some time and some times its working

here is my java code

```
package com.iseva.Servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import Connectionfactory.ConnectionFactory;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ValidateUser
 */
@WebServlet("/ValidateUser")
public class ValidateUser extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Connection cn=null;
    public void init()
    {

         cn=ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
         System.out.println("connection");  
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {


        String logintype=request.getParameter("t1");
        String username=    request.getParameter("t2");
        String  password=   request.getParameter("t3");
        PreparedStatement ps=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
           String result="";
        try {
            ps=cn.prepareStatement("select * from mydb.isevausers where logintype=? and passwords=? and username=?");
            ps.setString(1,logintype);
            ps.setString(2,password);
            ps.setString(3,username);
             rs=ps.executeQuery();
             boolean b=rs.next();

            // RequestDispatcher dispatcher=null;

             if(b==true)  
             {
                /* response.sendRedirect("form_1_IRCTC_PaymentEntry.html");*/
                 result="form1";
                 /*dispatcher =getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/form_1_IRCTC_PaymentEntry.html");

                 dispatcher.forward(request,response);*/

                 System.out.println("entered"); 
             }          
             else{     
                 result="notfound"; 
                 System.out.println("not found");                   
             }
                response.getWriter().write(result); 
        } catch (SQLException e) {   
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } 

        finally{ 
            if(cn!=null)
            {
                try {
                    cn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(ps!=null)
            {
                try {
                    ps.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(rs!=null)
            {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
        }

    }

}
```

when i try to access data base it gives following exception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1182)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4071)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4040)
    at com.iseva.Servlet.ValidateUser.doGet(ValidateUser.java:44)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1519)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1475)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

how to solve this issue ?
is it the problem of  `database` or my code, please help me out.
i closed all connection in finally block as suggested by sites, even it gives same .
this exception may occur when our `mysql` data base `idle` for some time. is it?
if yes, what should i do. or how to solve it.

this Exception also coming when i refresh server

```
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:64)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Dec 04, 2017 3:34:01 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkStateForResourceLoading
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1353)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1029)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkContextClassLoaders(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:90)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:63)
```

Comment: you are trying to access your database after your connection gets closed so make sure that your database connection is established...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.(how to use my sql ping with jdbc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47569694/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-no-operati)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one doGet() invocation your connection object are being closed so invoking it any next time after first usage will cause error because you won't have an opened connection.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    //opening a connection before accessing db
    cn=ConnectionFactory.getConnection();

    String logintype=request.getParameter("t1");
    String username=    request.getParameter("t2");
    String  password=   request.getParameter("t3");
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
       String result="";
    try {
        ps=cn.prepareStatement("select * from mydb.isevausers where logintype=? and passwords=? and username=?");
        ps.setString(1,logintype);
        ps.setString(2,password);
        ps.setString(3,username);
         rs=ps.executeQuery();
         boolean b=rs.next();

        // RequestDispatcher dispatcher=null;

         if(b==true)  
         {
            /* response.sendRedirect("form_1_IRCTC_PaymentEntry.html");*/
             result="form1";
             /*dispatcher =getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/form_1_IRCTC_PaymentEntry.html");

             dispatcher.forward(request,response);*/

             System.out.println("entered"); 
         }          
         else{     
             result="notfound"; 
             System.out.println("not found");                   
         }
            response.getWriter().write(result); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {   
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } 

    finally{ 
        if(cn!=null)
        {
            try {
                cn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(ps!=null)
        {
            try {
                ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(rs!=null)
        {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: so i should not close connection ?

Comment: @raj I updated my answer, you should close connection but you have to remember to open it before db access in method

Comment: yes its working but init() method will get executed on every request so that i kept it in initi method

Comment: i am getting another Exception please check it . i have edited my code